# getHours() returning incorrect value

Tags: javascript, date, formatting

I am using JavaScript Date object to convert milliseconds into a readable `minutes:seconds` formatted string. I need that to create a timer for a custom video player, where my JS interface receives the video duration info as a millisecond value.

It’s been a fairly trivial task, before I decided to support a possibility of having a video longer than 59 minutes. And then I encountered this problem: when I submit a millisecond value to the new Date object’s constructor, and then call `getHours()`, it will return something even if the number of milliseconds stands for a period of time less than an hour. The easiest way to see this in action is to feed it, say, 0.

[image]

I‘d expect it to return 0, but it always returns 12 (13 in Opera, which makes it even more weird). Is this a normal behaviour or is it a bug? Either way, how do I reliably detect whether my millisecond value is limited to just minutes and seconds or also includes hours?

Thanks.

UPD:

I‘ve tested it in Chrome 15 and Firefox 7 on OSX: same result as per the screenshot above. I cannot figure out how to use Opera Dragonfly console, but from what I see same thing happens in Opera, just with the value of 13 for `getHours()`.

Comment: You don't want to use the `Date` constructor here. `new Date( n )` returns a `Date` object with the date set to January 1st 1970 + `n` milliseconds, which is certainly not what you want...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, so what would be a good alternative?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/X5hn5/1/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, this is awesome, simple and reliable. Thank you!

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, I’ve extended and improved your function, in case you are interested: http://jsfiddle.net/j9zNa/1/

Comment: I've refactored it a bit... http://jsfiddle.net/j9zNa/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try calling `new Date(0).toString()` and see if there is a timezone affecting it?

Mine gives

```
"Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)"
```

Because I am on GMT+2, so `getHours` gives 2 to me.

The Unix epoch is GMT+0

Use `+new Date` to get reliable milliseconds at a point in time and keep it as number. Do not do any math within an actual date object.

Here is what I have used:

```
var toTimeString = function( secs ) {
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

    if( secs == null )
    return "";

days = ( secs / 86400 ) >> 0;
hours = ( secs % 86400 / 3600 ) >> 0;
minutes = ( secs % 3600 / 60 ) >> 0;
seconds = ( secs % 60 );    
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
hours = hours && hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;

return "" + ( days ? days+" - " : "" ) + ( hours ? hours+":" : "" ) + minutes + ":" + seconds;      
};
```

Apply custom formatting as required.. This actually takes seconds so divide milliseconds by 1000 to get seconds.

Comment: Right, timezone. I am in New Zealand, so that’s why in my case it adds 12 hours to 0. Would never have thought about that, thanks a lot! Though it does not fix the problem, it just shows how unreliable this approach actually is…

Answer (score 31):

I notice that, while people informed the User on how to fix his code, they did not inform him on how to do what he asked. The answer is pretty simple. Don't use function getHours(). Use getUTCHours(). This will bypass any timezone offset.

You'll still have problems if you ever need to go up to days, but, until then, the Date primitive will work just fine for what you use it for.

Comment: Thanks for this, GetUTCHours fixed my similar problem without the need for any other trickery.

Comment: This should be the answer. Solved my issue, which was the same problem the original "asker" had.

Comment: You made me login again on github just to upvote you. That's the spirit. Perfect conduct.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're not asking for this, and it's annoying to get answers that don't address your question, but in this case... I'd seriously recommend switching to Datejs before you do much work noodling around with JS's native Date() object which isn't overly powerful and can be a source of many troubles, especially if you've got to normalize time zones!
http://www.datejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds AND milliseconds value instead:

```
var sampleTime = new Date(1900,1,1,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: That would be February 1st, 1900.  Months are zero-based, Eg January is month `0`.

Comment: @gilly3 Good point, I forgot that. At any rate, the date is somewhat arbitrary. It is the time that is important in this case.